# Lucene .NET Snowball Analyzer does not exist in the namespace Lucene.Net.Analysis

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lucene.net

I am writing an application using ASP.NET Core and I have installed the Lucene .NET 3.0.3 Nuget package but when I tried to use the `SnowballAnalyzer` class, it seems that it is not appearing and the error `Lucene .NET Snowball Analyzer does not exist in the namespace Lucene.Net.Analysis` appears

[image]

[image]

I have already tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution but the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Nuget Packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net/), we can see Lucene .NET 3.0.3 is compatible with .Net Framework, but not apply to .Net Core.

From the Lucene website, it seems that the Lucene .NET version 4.8.0-beta00016 apply to .Net core application, you can try to use this version.

Besides, this issue relates Lucene .NET, if the above version still not working, you'd better to contact with them.